# TitanDB - Build a property index in descending order by timestamp

Tags: database, graph, titan, gremlin

**TitanDB 1.0.0** (on top of DynamoDB)

**Gremlin 3**

I've got a set of vertices with a label **a**. I have a property of type **long** on those vertices which corresponds to the time in milliseconds from 1970 UTC (timestamp of when the vertex was created.) When I pull back those vertices I want to be able to pull them back in **decsending** order.

How can I create an index on that property in the **decr** order in **Titan Management System**?

Documentation seems vague on that.

Closest thing I found is

`public RelationTypeIndex buildPropertyIndex(PropertyKey key,
                                            String name, 
                                            Order sortOrder,
                                            PropertyKey... sortKeys)`

But what do I put in as the **key** and sortKeys? I want to be able to pull the whole vertex ordered by the timestamp property

**Edit**: The only way I know of doing this at the minute is by duplicating that property on the edge and using a vertex centric index on the edge to increase the performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do something similar as I order by the release date of a particular product. If you want to execute `order().by("Value", decr)` efficiently then I highly recommend reading into mixed indices specified [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html). Mixed indices allow these operations to be done quickly.

An example of what you may be looking for:

```
TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
TitanManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
PropertyKey key = mgmt.makePropertyKey("TimeStamp").dataType(Long.class).make();
mgmt.buildIndex("timeStampIndex", Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildMixedIndex("search");
mgmt.commit();
```

The above index lets me execute the following query very quickly:

```
g.V().order().by("TimeStamp", decr);
```

Which gets me the time stamps in descending order. The above traversal will work without indexing but can be slow in large graphs.

Comment: Fantastic, yeah I was just playing around with doing that but I'm stuck with the index not going live and being stuck in REGISTERED status and success=false

Comment: Applying new indices to existing data can take some time. I have had ode luck just creating the index from the start. Creating the index later requires an explicit reindexing procedure. The page I linked in my answer provides more info on reindexing.